# Is there a way to know if a new venue was created in foursquare?

Tags: api, foursquare

I know you see if your friend(s) are checked in in a venue on foursquare but is there a way to see if a new venue was created in a certain place/city

Answer (score 0):

No, this functionality is not available through the foursquare API.

Answer (score 0):

Related discussion in this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/foursquare-api/vdKwGYCnuy0

There is no direct way to get this info via the API at the moment, but theoretically you could search for venues in certain areas in the city, cache venue IDs and check their createdAt value (see https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/venue). Repeat these steps on regular basis and compare against cached venue IDs. That way you can discover newly created venues. Of course, it may not be 100% reliable, especially in larger cities.